# JavaScript - keyboard shortcut without interfering with browser shortcut

Tags: javascript

I need to use Shift as a keyboard shortcut but I do not want to interfere with browser shortcuts that include Shift, for example Ctrl+Shift+i in Chrome. How do I make sure that Shift but nothing else was pressed?

The only solution I could think of so far is using setTimeout to check whether multiple keys were pressed without big time delay. However, this approach seems kind of hackerish and introduces the unwanted delay - I cannot execute immediately, I have to wait a second to see whether some other keys were also pressed.

Comment: mousetrap is useful: https://craig.is/killing/mice

Comment: `if(e.shiftKey && !(e.ctrlKey||e.metaKey))`...

Comment: *"I need to use Shift as a keyboard shortcut"* - You "need" to, or you want to? The shift key is designed to be used together with other keys, so as you've said: normal operation is to hold it down then press some other key. Having it do something else on its own seems a bit confusing for users.

Comment: @dandavis - that's what I needed, thanks. Do you want to post is as answer so I could mark it as solved and give you the karma you deserve?

Comment: nah, i'm sure there's a dupe, just glad to help